# Is it possible to update .xslb file format without cleaning existing data through java?

Tags: java, xlsb

i have a **.xlsb** file with data in it. I need to update the file by opening and writing new data in it through **java** language.

Is it possible to update a .xlsb file without clearing existing data ??

how to do it?

Comment: Yes- look at the apache POI library

Comment: Thanks!.Without clearing the workbook if we save the data then it will overwrite the existing data...This is what needed!!!

Comment: @pradpalnis please let me know how you read xlsb using POI open source...share some sample code.....to me it throws Unsupported exception